# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'enablePaging' dhtmlxgrid

Tags: jsp, dhtmlx

i have a jsp in which i have dhtmlxgrid for loading data.
To load data am using
var taskDetailsGrid = new dhtmlXGridFromTable('tablegrid');
 taskDetailsGrid.enablePaging(true,20,20, "recinfoArea");
it loads the data but pagination doesnt work.
it gives the following script error:
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'enablePaging'
am already using 
 `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">`
not able to find what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have missed to include one more js file - ext/dhtmlxgrid_pgn.js

Also, to enable paging in case of init from html, you need to call one more command

```
taskDetailsGrid.enablePaging(true,20,20, "recinfoArea");
taskDetailsGrid.setPage(0);
```